# memory management arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm creating several arrays in the app for example:

```
NSString *ItemsA[91];
 int GroupRep[11];
 double TaxR[16];
 short InputT[200];
 BOOL tmpEx[20];
```

and need these structures to be available thru the app until end of the app.
my questions are:
i. do I need to alloc the array of NSString explicitly or is it ok to initialize each array cell in this manner : ItemsA[10] = @"use option1"  for example.

ii. do i need to release or dealloc any of the above arrays

iii. i understand if i didn't specifically used alloc then the iOS will automatically do the retain/release thing. if so what about :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestur1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dispR)];
```

similarly I'm creating a class:

```
   myClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1+ipX, ipY, 320, rView.frame.size.height)];
    ...
    [myClass release]
```

and this class allocating his own stuff. do i need to release each one or just the whole class as above is enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, don't use language arrays to store objects.  Use `NSMutableArray` instances;  they  is relatively little overhead (probably immeasurable) and it is much more natural.

You'll also want to store any values for display in files that can be localized.  Thus, you'll want to load said files and, again, storing 'em in NSArray is much easier.   There is extensive documentation on the subject at developer.apple.com.

Finally, that looks like your app data.  Thus, you probably really want to have a proper model layer to manage said data.   Someday, you'll probably want to refactor the app to pull said data from a server and having a proper model layer will help you do so.

Note that you can typically hang the model -- the data management stuff -- off your application delegate.   Or you can reach it via a singleton somewhere.

This is a bit of a high level answer with a goal to try to direct you to a path that is a bit more in line with expected patterns.

Comment: thanks for your input. putting in place a data layer sounds like a good idea and will do when i'll refactor the app.

Comment: for now i just wanted to delve more into the memory management  and though i know the basic rules i.e. you own it if you alloc,copy or new the object, at times i'm not sure when exactly to release the obj memory. For example if i have a method that initialize an array with some values and calculations and that i have alloc inside it. I need  these values thru the app and at times need to call that method again if i need to recalculate new values so when do i release the alloc? at the end of the App or before or after i call that method? Hope it make sense, i can elaborate if needed

Comment: not sure i understand "the data management stuff -- off your application delegate" ... if you can elaborate its great.